# If $p\mid|G|$ then how many elements of order $p$ are there in $G$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ be a prime such that $p\mid|G|$ , then obviously $G$ has an element of order $p$ (by Cauchy's theorem) ; I would like to know exactly how many elements of order $p$ are there in the group ? Please help

Comment: Are you familiar with Sylow theorems?

Comment: @Ivan: yes ... how that helps ?

Comment: The element of order $p$ generates a cyclic subgroup of order $p$. So there are at least $(p - 1)$ elements of order $p$. (Perhaps you've already noticed that.)

Comment: @Taro: yes , true

Answer (score 4):

If $N_p$ is the number of subgroups of order $p$ in $G$ since any two of them intersect trivially, the total number $M(p)$ of elements of order $p$ is 
$$
M(p)=(p-1)N_p.
$$
When $p$ divides exactly the order of $G$, i. e. $|G|=pt$ with $(p,t)=1$, the number $N_p$ can be obtained applying Sylow's theorems.

If a higher power of $p$ divides $|G|$ the situation is more complex, as one needs to determine how the $p$-Sylows intersect each other.

Comment: Especially, it is not sufficient to know only $|G|$: $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ and $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^2$ are bot of order $4$, but have $1$ and $3$ elements of order $2$, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Something more can be said. Let's stick to the notation of Andrea Mori - let $M(p)$ denote the number of elements of order $p$ of $G$, then $$M(p) \equiv -1 \text { mod } p.$$
This follows easily from Sylow Theory or from the [proof of James McKay](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~yuvalf/McKay%20Another%20Proof%20of%20Cauchy%27s%20Group%20Theorem.pdf) of Cauchy's Theorem on the existence of elements of order $p$, if $p$ divides $|G|$.

Comment: For a generalization due to Frobenius: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/109027/applications-of-frobenius-theorem-and-conjecture

Comment: but , but both the materials say that the congruence holds for no. of solutions of $x^p=e$ , though I want the no. of solutions of $o(x)=p$ , shouldn't it be different ?

Comment: The solutions to $x^p = 1$ are precisely the elements of order $p$ and the neutral element. So there's exactly one extra guy. (This is very relevant for McKay's proof, because it excludes the possibility that there are $0$ elements of order p.)